# Is this weaker semialign a known abstraction?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a class which *looks* a lot like `SemiAlign`, but isn't:

```hs
class
  ( Functor f
  )
    => Weakalign f
  where
    {-# Minimal alignLeft | alignRight #-}
    alignLeft :: f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
    alignLeft =
      (fmap swap .) . flip alignRight
    alignRight :: f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
    alignRight =
      (fmap swap .) . flip alignLeft

swap :: Either a b -> Either b a
swap (Left x) =
  Right x
swap (Right x) =
  Left x
```

`alignLeft` aligns two structures always taking the left value on conflict, and `alignRight` does the same but preferring the right value.

Both can be defined in terms of `alignWith` or `align`:

```hs
alignLeft ::
  ( Semialign f
  )
    => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
alignLeft =
  alignWith go
  where
    go (This x) =
      Left x
    go (That y) =
      Right y
    go (These x _) =
      Left x
```

But neither `align` nor `alignWith` can be defined in terms of `alignLeft` or `alignRight`.  As a demonstration of why consider the following instance:

```hs
instance Weakalign ((,) a) where
  alignLeft =
    const
```

<sup>Thanks to [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner) for simplifying this example.</sup>

This is a perfectly valid `Weakalign` instance, but it cannot be extended to a law abiding `Semialign`.

That is a bit of a trivial example though. You might consider instead a parser type:

```hs
data Parser a b
  = Parser (a -> [(a, b)])
```

We could define `alignLeft` as a fall through operation, which tries the first parser and only if it fails tries the second parser.  For the same reason as the tuple there would be no way to extend the parser to a full `SemiAlign` instance.

I checked the `semialign` package and it doesn't seem like this corresponds to any existing class there.  However it seems like something that would already exist somewhere.  And I'm wondering if maybe it exists in another align-like package I don't know of, or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree and this isn't related to align.

Either way I'd prefer to use an extant library for this sort of thing instead of inventing my own.

Is this a known abstraction?

Comment: Um, your code isn't aligned too weakly, but broken rather too strongly... it's quite jarring to read.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not sure what you are saying.  I think you might be missing a word.  My code is written in Elm style.

Comment: Ok. I'm saying _it looks bad_, but tastes vary...

Comment: Seems like this could almost be a Semialign if you treated the `(b,c)` as the thing being aligned instead of just the `c`. (Only problem is it can't hold an arbitrary type, and has to hold a pair)

Comment: @user253751 The type provided is an example of a type that demonstrates that not all `Weakalign`s can be made into `Semialign`s.  You can change the type, to "fix" the issue, but the point was to show that there are some types which are not `Semialign`.

Comment: Can the counterexample be simplified to just be `newtype Core b c = Core (Maybe (b, c))`? Can it be simplified even further than that? Is `(,)` already a counterexample? I keep trying to see why this type can't be a `Semialign` instance and bouncing off, and I would be surprised if I'm the only one.

Comment: @DanielWagner Those are probably actually both good examples.  I feel like the given example is a bit more motivating as you can start to imagine why I would want to do this sort of operation on `KArrow` a little bit more than those other types.  But for the sake of a proof I think `(,)` is actually clearest.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) meets your needs. Something like `alignLeft` can be implemented this way:

```
alignLeft :: Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
alignLeft fa fb = (Left <$> fa) <|> (Right <$> fb)
```

Similarly for `alignRight`, with the arguments to `<|>` simply swapped:

```
alignRight :: Alternative f => f a -> f b -> f (Either a b)
alignRight fa fb = (Right <$> fb) <|> (Left <$> fa)
```

It isn't *exactly* the class you specified. In particular there's not really a good `(,)` instance (but see also [`Alt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.7/docs/Data-Functor-Alt.html#t:Alt)). But it should meet your needs for `Parser`, and is a very commonly provided operation in existing parser combinator libraries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure many parser libraries provide a different `Alternative` instance.  `a <|> b` usually will run both `a` and `b` and give you both responses on a success.  Although this observation is interesting, and for the parser case it does seem that, if you take the left value on conflict you get a valid `Alternative` instance, just with a greedy `some` and `many`.

Comment: @WheatWizard Some parser libraries return results from both alternatives, but some do commit when the first alternative is successful (i.e. have the behavior you describe in your question).